# Event won't trigger when subscribing to a casted object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I've got this code:

```
public class StateController
{
    public MainEventHandler EventHandler { get => eventHandler; }

    private State currentState;
    private MainEventHandler eventHandler = new();
    private MainRepository repository = new();
    private MainLogic logic = new();

    public void ActivateState(State toActivate)
    {
        if (toActivate is StateA) 
        {
            var properties = StateA.Properties();
            properties.eventHandler = eventHandler;
            properties.repository = repository;
            toActivate.Setup(properties);
        }
        else if (toActivate is StateB) 
        {
            var properties = StateB.Properties();
            properties.eventHandler = eventHandler;
            properties.logic = repository;
            toActivate.Setup(properties);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (eventHandler.onStart != null) 
            onStart();
    }

    public void DoLogic()
    {
        if (eventHandler.onCalculateLogic != null) 
            onCalculateLogic();
    }
}

public class MainEventHandler
{
    public delegate void OnStart();
    public event OnStart onStart;

    public delegate void OnCalculateLogic();
    public event OnCalculateLogic onCalculateLogic;
}

public class StateA: State
{
    public class Properties
    {
         public MainEventHandler eventHandler;
         public MainRepository repository;
    }

    private Properties props;

    public void Setup(object properties)
    {
        props = properties as Properties;
        props.eventHandler.onStart += Start;
    }

    public void CleanUp()
    {
        props.eventHandler.onStart -= Start;
    }

    private void Start() //Doesn't get triggered because onStart is null
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class StateB: State
{
    public class Properties
    {
         public MainEventHandler eventHandler;
         public MainLogic repository;
    }

    private Properties props;

    public void Setup(object properties)
    {
        props = properties as Properties;
        props.eventHandler.onCalculateLogic += Calculate;
    }

    public void CleanUp()
    {
        props.eventHandler.onCalculateLogic -= Calculate;
    }

    private void Calculate() //Doesn't get triggered because onCalculateLogic is null
    {
        ....
    }
}

public MainSceneController: Monobehavior
{
    private StateController stateController = new();
    private StateA firstState = new();
    private StateB secondState = new();
    Awake()
    {
        stateController.ActivateState(firstState);
    }

    Start()
    {
        if(stateController.EventHandler.onStart != null) stateController.EventHandler.onStart(); // stateController.EventHandler.onStart is null apparently even though I have set it in ActivateState()
        stateController.ActivateState(secondState);
    }

    Update()
    {
        if(stateController.EventHandler.onCalculateLogic != null) stateController.EventHandler.onCalculateLogic(); // stateController.EventHandler.onCalculateLogic is null apparently even though I have set it in ActivateState()

    }

}
```

I want to pass an object from `StateController` that has events that can be subscribed from inside the State. The parameter for `Setup()` is an object since we can have many types of properties. And the Properties is the only way the State will interact with the system outside of it. But unfortunately, the events wont get triggered at all because they are always null. Although as you can see, I have already added

```
`props.eventHandler.onStart += Start;`
```

and

```
`props.eventHandler.onCalculateLogic += Calculate;`
```

How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont dsee anything caling Start  as while Start is called for monobehaviours, Statecontroller isnt.

Comment: Ah yes. Maybe I need to edit the code a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Actually since `onStart` is an `event` it can only be invoked by the `MainEventHandler` class itself, **not** from the outside via `if(stateController.EventHandler.onStart != null) stateController.EventHandler.onStart();`! This should already have compiler errors and not even allow to be run at all

Comment: Please post a [mcve] .. the code you show here has various compiler errors / logic issues